# ¿Cómo "minimizar" una app en Android?

Tags: android

Necesito que mi app cierre sin perder su estado. Es decir, si me he quedado en un determinado `activity` y cierro la app, que al abrirla siga por donde me he quedado.

**La idea está que al pulsar el botón atrás la app se cierre y que al abrirla siga por donde se quedó.**

Gracias.

Comment: PacoPepe en ocasiones el código no es necesario pero es bueno agregar lo que hayas encontrado o investigado, para que la pregunta sea aún mejor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para minimizar la aplicación puedes realizarlo mediante un Intent, de esta forma usando [**ACTION_MAIN**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN), este código lo puedes llamar cuando

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent); 
}
```

> [**ACTION_MAIN**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)  Acción de actividad: Inicia como un punto de
>   entrada principal, no espera recibir datos.

También puedes realizarlo de esta forma usando el método **[moveTaskToBack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#movetasktoback)** :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

---

Recuerda enviar a background una aplicación, no garantiza que la aplicación 
"abra en donde se quedó", ya que el sistema operativo puede requerir memoria y tu aplicación podría iniciarse nuevamente, por ejemplo en el caso de abrir varias aplicaciones y regresar a la aplicación que previamente enviaste a segundo plano.